# How to get the data between two strings from a file in tcl?

Tags: tcl

In TCL Scripting:
I have a file in that i know how to search a string but how to get the line number when string is found.please answer me if it is possible

or

```
set fd [open test.txt r]
while {![eof $fd]} {
    set buffer [read $fd]
}

set lines [split $buffer "\n"]
if {[regexp "S1 Application Protocol" $lines]} {
    puts "string found"
} else {puts "not found"}
```

```
#puts $lines

#set i 0
#while {[regexp -start 0 "S1 Application Protocol" $line``s]==0}  {incr i
#puts $i
#}

#puts  [llength $lines]
#puts [lsearch -exact $buffer  S1]
#puts [lrange $lines 261 320]
```

in the above program i am getting the output as string found .if i will give the string other than in this file i am getting string not found.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll get a better response if you show us what you've done.

Comment: i tried with regexp command.i am able to find the string but how to find a line number from a file?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of 'a line' is just a convention that we layer on top of the stream of data that we get from a file.  So if you want to work with line numbers then you have to calculate them yourself.  The `gets` command documnetion contains the following example:

```
set chan [open "some.file.txt"]
set lineNumber 0
while {[gets $chan line] >= 0} {
    puts "[incr lineNumber]: $line"
}
close $chan
```

So you just need to replace the puts statement with your code to find the pattern of text you want to find and when you find it the value of `$line` gives you the line number.

To copy text that lies between two other lines I'd use something like the following

```
set chan [open "some.file.txt"]
set out [open "output.file.txt" "w"]
set lineNumber 0
# Read until we find the start pattern
while {[gets $chan line] >= 0} {
    incr lineNumber
    if { [string match "startpattern" $line]} {
        # Now read until we find the stop pattern
        while {[gets $chan line] >= 0} {
            incr lineNumber
            if { [string match "stoppattern" $line] } {
                close $out
                break
            } else {
                puts $out $line
            }
        }
    }
}
close $chan
```

Comment: thanks for your helping but it is working only for startin string. after that it is not working.it is copying all the file after finding first string

Comment: So what does your data file look like? What are the start and stop strings? Have you checked that your detecting the stop string correctly? Can you post a short datafile, 6 lines or so that doesn't work?

Comment: hi thanks for your solution.i am getting the data between the 2 strings but the error  message it is showing
C:\Users\atangutu\Desktop\anwesh>tclsh task1.tcl
can not find channel named "file1276940"
    while executing
"puts $out $line"
    ("while" body line 11)
    invoked from within
"while {[gets $chan line] >= 0} {
    incr lineNumber
    if { [string match "S1 Application Protocol" $line]} {
        # Now read until we find the s..."
    (file "task1.tcl" line 5)

C:\Users\atangutu\Desktop\anwesh>

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `fileutil::grep` command:

```
package require fileutil

# Search for ipsum from test.txt
foreach match [fileutil::grep "ipsum" test.txt] {
    # Each match is file:line:text
    set match      [split $match ":"]
    set lineNumber [lindex $match 1]
    set lineText   [lindex $match 2]

    # do something with lineNumber and lineText
    puts "$lineNumber - $lineText"
}
```

## Update

I realized that if the line contains colon, then `lineText` is truncated at the third colon. So, instead of:

```
    set lineText   [lindex $match 2]
```

we need:

```
    set lineText   [join [lrange $match 2 end] ":"]
```